# How to assign number to devices that appear on the same day?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have dataframe (df) , and it has device ids and local date columns . I want to assign user id to device ids that are always seen together on all local dates . I have provided the example below

```
device_id <- c("x1", "x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x4", "x4", "x5", 
           "x5", "x5", "x5", "x5", "x5", "x5", "x6", "x6", "x7", "x7", "x8", 
           "x8", "x9", "x9", "x9")

local_date <- c("2019-01-13", "2019-01-14", "2019-01-15", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", 
                "2019-01-10", "2019-01-11", "2019-01-12", "2019-01-11", "2019-01-12", 
                "2019-01-03", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-06", "2019-01-07", "2019-01-08", 
                "2019-01-13", "2019-01-23", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-10-23", 
                "2019-10-28", "2019-10-23", "2019-10-28", "2019-01-13", "2019-01-14", 
                "2019-01-15")

df <- data.frame(device_id, local_date)

df$local_date <- as.Date(df$local_date)
```

This is the dataframe what I want to create .

```
expected_df <- data.frame(device_id=c("x1", "x9", "x2", "x6", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x7", "x8"), 
                          user_id=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6))


expected_df  
#   device_id user_id
# 1        x1       1
# 2        x9       1
# 3        x2       2
# 4        x6       2
# 5        x3       3
# 6        x4       4
# 7        x5       5
# 8        x7       6
# 9        x8       6
```

If you observe x1 & x9 are both seen together on the same local dates , thats why they are assigned same user id ... So is the case with x7 & x8 ....

How do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the basic logic from @January, another `tidyverse` possibiliy could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(device_id) %>%
 summarise(footprint = str_c(str_sort(local_date), collapse = ";")) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 transmute(device_id,
           user_id = group_indices(., footprint))

  device_id user_id
  <chr>       <int>
1 x1              5
2 x2              1
3 x3              3
4 x4              4
5 x5              2
6 x6              1
7 x7              6
8 x8              6
9 x9              5
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know the `group_indices()` function.

Answer (score 5):

How about the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(device_id) %>% 
       mutate(footprint=paste(sort(as.character(local_date)), collapse=";")) %>% 
       ungroup %>% 
       mutate(id=as.numeric(factor(footprint))) %>% 
       filter(!duplicated(device_id)) %>% arrange(id)
```

Explanation:

For each device, we create a footprint string – the dates on which the device was seen. Next, we assign numeric ids (with help of `factor`) based on the footprint.

Base R:

```
d2id <- tapply(df$local_date, df$device_id, function(x) paste(x, collapse=";"))
d2id <- data.frame(names(d2id), id=d2id)
d2id$id <- as.numeric(factor(d2id$id))
d2id <- d2id[ order(d2id$id), ]
```